# Accessing HTML elements inside a React component

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I have a React component *InputComponent* which I cannot edit, and I would like to get a reference to one of its inner divs. (for example for the purpose of focusing on the input field).

```
const RefsExamplePage = () => {

    return (
        <div>

            <div>
                <InputComponent
                title="Test component"
                ></InputComponent>
            </div>

        </div>

    )
}

export default RefsExamplePage;
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: if you ca't edit; check if its children have a specific classname or id to pick them by that; or if nothing special found; re-Implement this simple component your self with proper `ref` passed to its children

Comment: I think you might have an X Y problem here. Perhaps instead of stating that you need to edit it tell us what you would like to achieve at a higher level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which I cannot edit

If you can't edit it, the only thing you can do is pass `ref` to it and hope the `InputComponent` have refs implemented.

e.g.

```
const RefsExamplePage = () => {

    // use inputRef.current to access the input reference
    const inputRef = React.useRef()    

    return (
        <div>

            <div>
                <InputComponent
                    ref={inputRef}
                    title="Test component"
                />
            </div>

        </div>

    )
}
```

If this doesn't work or give you some error, you **will need to modify the `InputComponent`**

Answer (score 1):

If `InputComponent` doesn't provide `ref` you can wrap its parent (the `div` container) then set `ref` for it:

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const RefsExamplePage = () => {
    const container = useRef();
    return (
        <div>

            <div ref={container}>
                <InputComponent
                title="Test component"
                ></InputComponent>
            </div>

        </div>

    )
}

export default RefsExamplePage;
```

Then you can access the child element through the div's `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `useRef()` to create a ref to the component itself. This way you can get the components reference and you can use `.current` property of it to get the underlying DOM:

```
const RefsExamplePage = () => {

    const inputRef = useRef();

    const getInput = e => {
       // here get the any dom node available
       inputRef.current.querySelector('input').focus();
    };

    return (....
           <InputComponent 
             ref={inputRef} 
             onClick={getInput} 
             title="Test component"/> // <---if no child are passed change to self closing
        ....)
}
```